# GCC. Регистры спроецированные на память

Tags: c, gcc, микроконтроллеры

Пишу программу для 32-разрядного процессора без MMU.(Microblaze 1.4.1)
В программе в области памяти c адреса **0xC0000000** расположены регистры устройства, всего 16 регистров **DR0...DR15**. Т.о.
DR0 - 0xC0000000,
DR1 - 0xC0000002,
...
Обращение к этим регистрам должно производиться по определенным правилам:
1. При чтении и записи читаться должно строго 1 регистр, читать 2 регистра командой чтения 32-битного слова нельзя.
2. Запись возможна только в регистр целиком(т.е. нельзя записывать по отдельности старший или младший байты).
Вопрос: как "объяснить" эти правила компилятору? Я хочу, чтобы в коде это выглядело как:

```
struct regs
{
    uint16_t dr[16];
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Совершенно стандартная же задача! Вот так это решают в ST:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
  #define   __I     volatile             /*!< Defines 'read only' permissions                 */
#else
  #define   __I     volatile const       /*!< Defines 'read only' permissions                 */
#endif
#define     __O     volatile             /*!< Defines 'write only' permissions                */
#define     __IO    volatile             /*!< Defines 'read / write' permissions              */

#define PERIPH_BASE           ((uint32_t)0x40000000) /*!< Peripheral base address in the alias region */
#define APB2PERIPH_BASE       (PERIPH_BASE + 0x10000)
#define GPIOA_BASE            (APB2PERIPH_BASE + 0x0800)
#define GPIOB_BASE            (APB2PERIPH_BASE + 0x0C00)

typedef struct
{
  __IO uint32_t CRL;
  __IO uint32_t CRH;
  __IO uint32_t IDR;
  __IO uint32_t ODR;
  __IO uint32_t BSRR;
  __IO uint32_t BRR;
  __IO uint32_t LCKR;
} GPIO_TypeDef;

#define GPIOA               ((GPIO_TypeDef *) GPIOA_BASE)
#define GPIOB               ((GPIO_TypeDef *) GPIOB_BASE)
```

Ну и пользоваться этим: `GPIOA->ODR = GPIOB->IDR - 42;`

Ключевое слово - volatile, чтобы отбить у компилятора желание что-нибудь оптимизировать: выкинуть запись, поменять обращения местами и т.д.